# Lebesgue integration of 1/{|x|^{\alpha}}

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I would like to know for which values of $\alpha$, the following statement holds:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\dfrac{1}{\Vert x\Vert^{\alpha}}<\infty.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: There is no $\alpha$. Either the integral diverges at $0$ or at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no $\alpha$! Either integral  diverges on $\{\|x\| \leq 1\}$ or the integral diverges on $\{\|x\| > 1\}$

Comment: When is it convergent in the unit ball? Thx.

Comment: The integral over the unit ball is finite iff $\alpha <n$.